# Importing users to Sharepoint from Database

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using Sharepoint 2007 to keep a central database, while giving the users an Access 2007 FE with linked tables.

I would like to have a file (access db, or xls) with all users, their pass, and a checkbox or something similar, with user's permissions (only one common type, like "Read,no Write"); and import it to Sharepoint. Do you know if it is possible?

I mean, something like: 4 users, 3 tables, and having a file like:

```
USER          PASS          TableI         TableII       TableIII
User1         PassUser1     Ok             No            No
User2         PassUser2     Ok             Ok            No
User3         PassUser3     No             No            Ok
User4         PassUser4     No             Ok            Ok
```

And using it to handle Sharepoint's site permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I used Simego's Data Synchronisation Studio to import users from Active Directory. It can do other data sources so it's probably worth a try. http://www.simego.com/Products/Data-Synchronisation-Studio